# How to calculate age from D.O.B?

Tags: android, date

I want to calculate age from D.O.B. I am getting date of birth from below code. Now i want to calculate user age and I want to show age in another textView. How can I achieve this ?

```
dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy", Locale.US);

public void setDateTimeField() {
        date();

        Calendar newCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        fromDatePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                Calendar newDate = Calendar.getInstance();
                newDate.set(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
                txtDatePicker.setText(dateFormatter.format(newDate.getTime()));
            }

        },newCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), newCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), newCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));

    }

    public void date(){

        txtDatePicker.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                fromDatePickerDialog.show();
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [Joda](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/), which simplifies date/time calculations (Joda is also the basis of the new standard Java date/time apis, so you'll be learning a soon-to-be-standard API).

Java 8 has [something very similar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) and is worth checking out.

e.g.

```
LocalDate birthdate = new LocalDate (1970, 1, 20);
LocalDate now = new LocalDate();
Years age = Years.yearsBetween(birthdate, now);
```

which is as simple as you could want.

Great examples for using dates with Java 8: [Java 8 Date Examples](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/java-8-datetime-api-tutorial/)

Happy Coding!

Comment: Android studio giving error - Cannot resolve symbol 'LocalDate'.

Comment: have you added joda lib ?

Comment: ya Now its working fine but how to set dynamically date in LocalDate birthdate = new LocalDate (1970, 1, 20); I am getting this error - java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: yyyy,dd,mm

Comment: separate dynamic date into year month and day using calender object, after that pass it to LocalDate respectively.

Comment: Calendar newDate = Calendar.getInstance();
                newDate.set(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
                LocalDate birthdate = new LocalDate (newDate.getTime());
                LocalDate now = new LocalDate();
                Years age = Years.yearsBetween(birthdate, now);
                txtAge.setText(String.valueOf(age.getYears()));